# how to use gi in windows

Tags: python, pip, gstreamer

i'm trying to run this code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
```

but is give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r0504\Desktop\try.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

when I try to install pygobject is give me another error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' 'c:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vv312rqa\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo
       cwd: None
  Complete output (33 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-45.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (583 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.34.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
  Collecting pycairo
    Using cached pycairo-1.19.0.tar.gz (200 kB)
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycairo
      Running setup.py install for pycairo: started
      Running setup.py install for pycairo: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\r0504\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irw93yia\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\r0504\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irw93yia\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0_k2qosq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vv312rqa\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vv312rqa\overlay\Include\pycairo'
           cwd: C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irw93yia\pycairo\
      Complete output (18 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
      copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
      copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
      copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
      running build_ext
      building 'cairo._cairo' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=19 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=0 -Ic:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo/device.obj
      device.c
      C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irw93yia\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\r0504\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irw93yia\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\r0504\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irw93yia\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0_k2qosq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vv312rqa\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vv312rqa\overlay\Include\pycairo' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' 'c:\users\r0504\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vv312rqa\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel pycairo Check the logs for full command output.
```

this is after I download visual studio... before I had another error.
windows 10, python 3.7.6

thank you very much!!

Comment: That python module is written in c++, so you need a c++ compiler.

Comment: Let me quote you for you :) `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: @jordanm I download visual stodio c++ and then I got another error, I update the post. thank you :)

Comment: `C:\Users\r0504\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irw93yia\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory`. You need the cairo c++ library.

Comment: @jordanm how can I do it? I just not understand anything in c++ sorry

Answer (score 0):

The last version of gi I know for Windows is several years old, 2017, running python 3.4 :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/pygi-aio-3.24.1_rev1-setup_049a323fe25432b10f7e9f543b74598d4be74a39.exe/download

from this date, I found nothing else but the necessity to install Msys2. I must admit it runs fairly well, and I am able to build pure Windows installers with py2exe. Msys2 is a Linux environment running in Windows, so you need to know at least the basics of Linux to be able to use it.

I searched several times on the net,and never found anything else in 2021. Presently I run Python 3.9 and the last versions of gi etc. without trouble.

Comment: Hi! You wrote comment back in 2021, maybe sth changed since that time? I also found a way to run gstreamer only with msys. On https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/gst-python/1.12.4.html mentioned it should be multi platform, but i wasn't successful to run it on windows

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of any change in the situation for gi, Python and Windows.